# Installation with Visual Studio 2010 MSI and updates to c# projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

Every time a new version of the project is built, the installer project in the solution gets updated as well. When I take that new MSI created, and run it on a machine which has an earlier version of it, will it automatically update the older one?

Comment: you can control this in the setup project properties, if you do not change product ID and package ID (those are GUIDs for what I remember) and at every build you update the version number in the setup project and you have also set the property to execute the update, then yes, you will get all running smooth as you assumed in your question.

Comment: This is my answer. Thanks a lot Davide!

Comment: @Davide You should post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control this in the setup project's properties; if you do not change product ID and package ID (those are GUIDs for what I remember) and at every build you update the version number in the setup project and you have also set the property to execute the update, **then yes**, you will get all running smooth as you assumed in your question.